# How to define function for pandas qcut label?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas.qcut for dividing data into 5 groups, and want to label each group based on the qcut min and max score.

For example, I tried on "age" data from data frame column.

```
df['age group'] = pd.qcut(df['age'], 5)
```

and it resulted in

```
Categories (5, interval[float64]): [(37.999, 61.0] < (61.0, 67.0] < (67.0, 73.0] < (73.0, 78.0] < (78.0, 93.0]]
```

The expected result is to give label for each group automotically based on min and max value, e.g. 
Categories 1 label would be "37.999 to 60.999", etc.

For now I did the labeling manually looking at each category range. How should I define the label to make it as expected? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the categories:

```
df['age group'] = pd.qcut(df['age'], 5)
df['age group'].cat.categories = [f'{i.left} to {i.right}' for i in df['age group'].cat.categories]
```

Comment: This works well, but I guess I need to change the word "to" to "<" since it will be biased if the right limit is another group's left limit. Thanks!